# Getting Error Response using axios on Client Side in React

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am learning react. I have written backend code as follows.

```
router.post('/signup', async (req,res)=>
{
    try
    {
        const user = new User(req.body);
        const token = await user.generateAuthToken();
        res.cookie('authToken', token);
        res.status(201).send();

    }
    catch(err)
    {
        res.status(400).send({err: "User Already Exists"});
    }
})
```

on fontend, I am using axios to send request. my code is as follows.

```
e.preventDefault();
        try
        {
            const res = await axios.post("/signup",{email, password});  
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            console.log(err)
        }
```

My Question is how can I get `User Already Exists` this statement from backend in case of error.

Comment: `console.log(res)` in the try block on the front end. The request will be successful so your code won't enter the catch block in the front end.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava in case of status code 400 in backend, does the catch block not run in frontend?

Comment: It will run on the back end, but the response with error message is a valid one, and from the front end perspective, the request is successful. So the catch on the front end will not execute

Comment: i am using `console.log(res.status)` in the try block of frontend. in case of `status code 201` in backend it gives me 201 printed on frontend but in case of `status code 400`, it does not show the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of any response other than 2xx from backend, the catch block runs on frontend and we can get data using `err.response` object. To get data, use the following code

```
try
{
   const res = await axios.post("/signup",{email, password})
   console.log(res.data)
}
catch(err)
{
   if(err.response)
   {
      console.log(err.response.data)
   }
}
```

Comment: So doesn't this mean you were getting the response already in `console.log(err)` ?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava it was only showing `POST http://localhost:8000/signup 400 (Bad Request)` and nothing else..

Answer (score 0):

Something else broke your function and you have to debug what is wrong here:

```js
catch(err){
    console.log(err)
    res.status(400).send({err: "User Already Exists"});
}
```

Comment: nothing wrong with backend, visit the following link it gives instructions with handling error.   https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#handling-errors